# Trouble detecting deadlocks using SOSEX and the dlk command

Tags: debugging

I've put together a simple console application that deadlocks using Monitor and I am trying to detect that deadlock using the SOSEX debugging extension. I get the following message when using the dlk command.

*Examining SyncBlocks...
Failed to retrieve sync block data. Error = 0x80070057.
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock instances...
Failed to load App Domain store data. Error = 0x80070057
Failed to retrieve heap data. Error = 0x80070057.
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Failed to load App Domain store data. Error = 0x80070057
Scanning for ReaderWriterLockSlim instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
No deadlocks detected.*

Any ideas on what the error means and how to fix it?
Thanks